# Medical diagnosis systems based on artificial neural networks

Tags: neural-networks, applications, reference-request

Are there any medical diagnosis systems that are already used somewhere that are based on artificial neural networks?

Comment: Great and salient question.  My general sense is that NNs are getting very good at this, and I wouldn't be surprised if this is an area where automata exceed humans, in all but exceptional cases.  Welcome to SE:AI!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there are many, actually. A Google search turned this paper [Artificial Neural Networks in Medical Diagnosis](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/285912467_Artificial_Neural_Networks_in_Medical_Diagnosis) (2011) by Al-Shayea up.

Not only are they used in disease diagnosis, but even with things like prescribing medicines. In fact, the top project for a hackathon at my school analysed thousands of research articles, and took a patient's medication history as input, to best recommend them specific medicines. Check it [out](https://devpost.com/software/neurolens).