# Is there an AI system that, given a patient's symptoms, produces a diagnosis and suggests a treatment?

Tags: applications, reference-request, chat-bots, resource-request, healthcare

Is there an AI system (preferably, one that interacts with the human, such as a chatbot like [this one](https://www.pandorabots.com/pandora/talk?botid=b8d616e35e36e881)) that, given some input (e.g. entered into the system by writing text), such as a person's physical history and symptoms (of a certain disease), produces a diagnosis of the disease and/or suggests medications or a treatment to improve the condition of the patient?

Comment: Maybe have a look at this question: [https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/18584/2444](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/18584/2444).